# how to resize columns in datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using following method to fill datagridview from SQL

```
public bool _MFillGridView(string pQuery, ref DataGridView _pDgv)
{
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_CObjectsofClasses._obj_CConnectionString._MGetConnectionString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(pQuery, con))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    _pDgv.DataSource = dt;
                    _pDgv.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (DataColumn DC in dt.Columns)
        {
            _pDgv.Columns[DC.ColumnName].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;

            if (DC.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
               _pDgv.Columns[DC.ColumnName].DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Format = _pDateFormat };
               _pDgv.Columns[DC.ColumnName].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            }
            else if (DC.DataType == typeof(decimal))
            {
               _pDgv.Columns[DC.ColumnName].DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Format = _CObjectsofClasses._obj_CNumbricFunction._MFormatNo("0") };
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

and here I am using like this;

```
_MFillGridView("My SQL query here", ref MydatagridviewToFill);
```

above code works perfectly but I am facing column width problems. I want to to pass column index and `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode` and column width to resize columns like

```
coloumn[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
coloumn[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
coloumn[2].Width = 200;
```

and all other columns which are not provided should be set to `AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.NotSet;`

please suggest me to what I change in code.

Comment: It's a **column** (not a *coloumn* as you keep spelling it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question above, I believe this is what you want?

```
private void ResizeColumns(DataGridView gridview, int column, int width, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode mode)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gridview.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        if (i.Equals(column))
        {
            gridview.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = mode;
            gridview.Columns[i].Width = width;
        }
        else
        {
            gridview.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
        }
    }
}
```

## Update

Ok still not sure I understand what you are after but I think this may point you in the right direction

```
public bool _MFillGridView(string pQuery, ref DataGridView _pDgv, int columnIndex, int width)
{
    using (var dt = new DataTable())
    {
        // ... Code to retrieve data from Database ...

        for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            var column = dt.Columns[i];
            if (column.DataType == typeof (DateTime))
                _pDgv.Columns[column.ColumnName].DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle {Format = _pDateFormat};
            else if (column.DataType == typeof (decimal))
                _pDgv.Columns[column.ColumnName].DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle {Format = _CObjectsofClasses._obj_CNumbricFunction._MFormatNo("0")};

            // Do your DataGridView formatting here
            if (_pDgv.Columns[column.ColumnName].Index.Equals(columnIndex)) // Check your Column index on the control
            {
                _pDgv.Columns[column.ColumnName].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            }
            else
            {
                _pDgv.Columns[column.ColumnName].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
                _pDgv.Columns[column.ColumnName].Width = width;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you are right, but this is for only 1 Column, what abt multiple Columns...please refer my question in example I am using 3 Column, that are Column[0],Column[1],Column[2]. I want to pass column list, width list, AutoSizeMode list

Comment: what do you mean by "only 1 column"? it is a loop so all columns will be handle one way or the other. On the other hand if you mean that you want only a specific list of columns to be formatted than I can update the method for you

Comment: Yes sir I want to pass parameters in _MFillGridView method and your provided loop should be in _MFillGridView. How I can make it, Please Update your Answer.

Comment: Ok I have updated the code, still not sure what 'parameters' you are referring to through.

Comment: OK I solved my problem using your code i just change int columnIndex, int width to List<int> columnIndex, List<int> width. Thanks for Help and +1

Comment: Good stuff! Glad to be of assistance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using @Mo Patel i just change int columnIndex, int width to List columnIndex, List width